# Showing convergence to $\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the sequence $$a_n =  (1-\frac{1}{n})^n$$ converges to $\frac{1}{e}$.

So far, I have started with the fact that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$$

Through some manipulation, I've gotten to showing that by taking reciprocals on both sides, we can say that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n = \frac{1}{e}$$

Did I make an algebraic error? Or is there a way to definitively say that having $n+1$ in my second numerator does not matter?

Comment: Multiply by $\frac{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}$. You get your exponent, there is a factor $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}$ that remains, and this one goes to $1$.

Answer (score 4):

We begin with the limit definition of $e$ written as

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{e\equiv \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n} \tag 1$$

---

Next, we note that

> $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n \tag 2$$

It is evident that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is bounded above by $1$.  Then, using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we find that

> $$\left(1-\frac1{n}\right) \le \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n \le 1$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem yields

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n =1 \tag 3$$

---

Putting together $(1)-(3)$, we find that

> $$\begin{align}
> 1&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\\\\
> &\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
> &=\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)\,\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\right)\\\\
> &=e\,\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
> e^{-1}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n
> \end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You have got to be freaking kidding me! This is really awesome and saves me the problem how to explain this to students without they feeling they should try to commit suicide.  +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Wow!  You just made my weekend!  Thank you for this very nice note.  -Mark

Comment: My pleasure, Mark. It is not that often I find here pretty nice ideas to deal with things that can be pretty elementary but troublesome.

Comment: @DonAntonio Don, I've seen you post many really solid solutions.  And I've learned a lot from you and others here MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\right]=1\cdot\frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{e}.
$$
Now, let $m=n+1$, and note that $m\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be 
$$
a_n=(1+1/n)^n=:1+a_n',\qquad b_n=(1-1/n)^n 
$$
Since you already know that $a_n\to e$, it is sufficient to prove that $a_n b_n\to 1$.

Now
$$
a_n b_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=1-c_n,
$$
where
$$
|c_n|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^k\binom{n}{k}\leq\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\binom{n}{k}=\frac{a_n'}{n} 
$$
Since $a_n'\to e-1$, it follows $c_n\to 0$.